# How to set timeout for ReadDocumentAsync (Azure Cosmos Db)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I set the timeout to be `1` second using the following :

```
DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(DocumentDbEndpointUrl),
            DocumentDbKey,
            new ConnectionPolicy { 
ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway, 
ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
RequestTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1) });
```

Then read :

```
return await documentClient.ReadDocumentAsync<Response>(docUri, 
new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(key)});
```

But it doesn't respect the timeout value I set, and sometime timeout in > `5` seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this,

```
        var connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
        {
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
            ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
            RequestTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0),
            MaxConnectionLimit = 1000,
            RetryOptions = new RetryOptions
            {
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 10,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 60
            }
        };

        _client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(_uri), _key, connectionPolicy);
```

Comment: Sorry, how does this make sense? This Timespan indicates 1 hour of timeout. Am I missing something?

Comment: It can be configured

Comment: But that doesn't really answer his question on why there is a problem right? Basically all this answer says is "Change the ConnectionMode from Gateway to Direct"